# Today Google Trends for specific query

Tags: google-trends

I fetch necessary data from Google Trends using the following URL:
[http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=doctor&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3&date=4/2013+3m&hl=en-US](http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=doctor&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3&date=2/2013%203m&hl=en-US)

But the output of Google Trends does not contain data for yesterday and today (even if extrapolated by the past hours). For example, the abovementioned URL on 2013-04-28 returned JavaScript code with the following fragment:

```
...,
{"c":[{"v":new Date(2013,3,26),"f":"Friday, April 26, 2013"},{"v":65.0,"f":"65"}]},
{"c":[{"v":new Date(2013,3,27),"f":"Saturday, April 27, 2013"},{"v":null}]},
{"c":[{"v":new Date(2013,3,28),"f":"Sunday, April 28, 2013"},{"v":null}]},
...
```

Notice null values for April 27, 28.
But, as we know, "Hot Trends" are available with hourly granularity. That assumes Google possesses enough data to give us the *"complete answer"* even for the trends request related to *specific* query not only for the "hottest".

Does anybody know a hack how to fetch from Google Trends **up-to-date** daily data for specific query? Or, may be, workarounds to derive similar trends data from other sources?

Comment: anybody have any ideas? I find the same for searching for trends in the api using the interestOverTime endpoint